# can just run one test in ActiveModel source code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am walking through the source code of rails.
in the directory of activemodel. we have a Rakefile. there is a task can run all the test in the test directory.

```
bundle exec rake test
Finished in 1.335200s, 530.2576 runs/s, 1492.6603 assertions/s.

708 runs, 1993 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

I want to know if is there a way that can let me just run one test in that directory.

for example : just only run this file rails/activemodel/test/cases/errors_test.rb

or can I just test one case in that file?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to accomplish this, but for your use case, you could just update the line where it lists all the test files to be a specific file. For example [this](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activemodel/Rakefile#L11) line in the `Rakefile` could be updated to:

```
t.test_files = Dir.glob("#{dir}/test/cases/errors_test.rb")
```

Answer (score 0):

After Reading the doc of rake.
I find a way:

> If rake is invoked with a “TEST=filename” command line option, then
>   the list of test files will be overridden to include only the filename
>   specified on the command line. This provides an easy way to run just
>   one test.

so for example:

```
bundle exec rake test TEST=test/cases/callbacks_test.rb
```

this works.